# Forming Elastic search query with extra quotation marks

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to mimic Kibana's search query via Elasticsearch's query string. For e.g. in Kibana I can search like this with the quotation marks:

```
"ABC" AND "CDE"
```

When I try to create this query string it throws a syntax error:

```
{
"query": {
"query_string": {
"fields": ["messages"]
"query": ""ABC" AND "CDE"" (syntax error occurs here)
}
}
}
```

I know I can just query it without the extra quotation marks but I need to append user's input to the query string which will contain those extra quotation marks. How can I form this query so that it can accept the quotation marks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can either escape the quotes in your query field

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["messages"],
      "query": "\"ABC\" AND \"CDE\""
    }
  }
}
```

or wrap the query value in triple quotes

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["messages"],
      "query": """
        "ABC" AND "CDE"
      """
    }
  }
}
```

(your example was also missing a comma between the fields and query field)

Comment: The above queries work on Kibana's console but somehow it doesn't work correctly in JS. This is my query in js: {
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["messages"],
      "query":
        "" + '"""'+ '\n' + "ABC" AND "CDE" + '\n'+ '"""'+""
    }
  }
}The number of hits are not the same as the oone I get in Kibana. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to escape the quotations:

```
GET index-2021.02.21/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": "\\"ABC\\""
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```